# Ajax AutoCompleteExtender not calling wcf service

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf

I am working in asp.net 4.0 (vs2010).  I am trying to implement an AutoCompleteExtender ajax control.  At first I attempted to use a page method but since I have the extender in a usercontrol, I cannot use this method.  I have spent several days researching and have determined that I need to use an Ajax-Enabled WCF Service.  So I did this.  I broke away from my application and created a test application that mimicks what i am attempting to do and it works.  I put the control on the page, point it to the service and voila, it fires the event and works great.  So I ported the code with the necessary changes over to my main application and it doesn't work.  By doesn't work I mean it doesn't fire the event in the service.  I suspect that the issue is the ServicePath but I have tried many, many different paths and nothing seems to work.
Here is the code from the control:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <div style="float: left">
        <asp:Label runat="server">Site Id:</asp:Label><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSiteId" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"     OnTextChanged="TextChangedEvent"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 200px; padding-left: 20px; margin-right: 5px">
        <asp:Label runat="server">Entered Site Id's:</asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptSiteIds" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptSiteIds_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton id="lnkRemove" Width="50" runat="server" Text="remove" CommandName="remove"></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:Label ID="lblItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Item") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate>
                <br>
            </SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>

    <Controls:ConfirmationModal runat="server" ID="MaxSiteIdConfirmation" ModalType="Alert" OnOkClicked="ConfirmationOk_Clicked"
        Title="Site Id Validation" Message="Too many site id's"
        Width="300" />

    <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
        runat="server"
        ID="AutoCompleteExtender"
        TargetControlID="txtSiteId" 
        CompletionSetCount="10"
        UseContextKey="True"
        ServicePath="~\DataServices\WebDataServices.svc"
        ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" />


</ContentTemplate>
```

Here is the code from the Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;


namespace Web.Internal.DataServices
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "WebDataServices")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =                     AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class WebDataServices
{
    // To use HTTP GET, add [WebGet] attribute. (Default ResponseFormat is     WebMessageFormat.Json)
    // To create an operation that returns XML,
    //     add [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)],
    //     and include the following line in the operation body:
    //         WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
    [OperationContract]
    public void DoWork()
    {
        // Add your operation implementation here
        return;
    }

    // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
    [OperationContract]
    public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        //return names;
        String[] autoCompleteWordList = (from s in CreateList()
                                         where s.Contains(prefixText)
                                         select s).Take(count).ToArray();

        return autoCompleteWordList;
    }

    private string[] CreateList()
    {
        using (UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork("DataService"))
        {
            return new ServiceDetailsBusiness(uow).GetDistinctIds().ToArray();
        }

    } 
}
```

}

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a couple of things:

Your service methods need to be decorated with the following attributes:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
```

Update your OperationContract attribure so it looks like this:

```
[OperationContract WebInvoke(Method="POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Add the following code snippet right before the `return autoCompleteWordList` statement in your method.

```
    if (WebOperationContext.Current != null)
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Also, make sure you can execute the web service call correctly from a web browser and that all the metadata information shows up correctly. Have you added any EndPoint information to your web.config file?

Let me know if that works out.